# Let $E = \{a+b \mid a \in (-1,0], b \in [2,3) \}$. Determine $\sup(E)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E = \{a+b \mid a \in (-1,0], b \in [2,3) \}$. Determine $\sup(E)$.

Since $a\le 0 \implies a \le 3-b$. Now from $a \le 3-b$ we have that $a+b\le 3$, thus $3$ is an upper bound for $E$. Now in order to prove that $\sup(E) = 3$ one has to show that $$a+b>3-\varepsilon, \forall \varepsilon >0.$$

From here $a+b > 3- \varepsilon \implies b>3-\varepsilon-a > 3-\varepsilon-(-1) = 4- \varepsilon$, but this only holds for $\varepsilon >2$. What might be happening here?

Comment: I think you just need to show for each $\epsilon$ the *existence* of an $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b>3-\epsilon$, but it seems like you're assuming that that statement must be true *for all* a and b, which is clearly going to cause problems.

Comment: "...one has to show that $a + b > 3 -\varepsilon, \forall \varepsilon > 0$" this is incorrect. You might want to see again the definition of supremum or theorem related to it. Something like "no other upper bound less than $3$" is enough.

Comment: @Azlif Isn’t the definition for an upper bound $a$ say. If $\forall \varepsilon > 0, a - \varepsilon$ is not an upper bound then $a$ is the supremum of $E$. (http://mathonline.wikidot.com/epsilon-definition-of-the-supremum-and-infimum-of-a-bounded).

Comment: @Wondera your quantifier is reversed. From the Theorem 1 in the link that you give, It should be "For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist $a\in (-1,0)$ and $b\in [2,3)$ such that $a + b > 3 -\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof in general :-

If $A$ and $B$ be two bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Then if $C=\{a+b|a\in A,b\in B\}$.

$Sup(C)=Sup(A)+Sup(B)$.

$a+b\leq sup(A)+sup(B)\,\,\forall a\in A\,\,and\,\,b\in B$.

So $sup(A)+sup(B)$ is upper bound of the set C.

Let $\varepsilon>0 $ be any positive real number.

Then corresponding to $\displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ , $\exists a'\in A\,\, and\,\,b'\in B $ such that
$\displaystyle a'>Sup(A)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $\displaystyle b'>sup(B)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

(This is by property of Supremum). i.e. Any real number less than supremum fails to be an upper bound. In other words you can find a member of the set which exceeds the number which is less than the supremum. Thus making the name justified of Least Upper Bound.)

Hence for $a'+b'\in C$.we have:-

$\displaystyle a'+b'>sup(A)+sup(B)-\varepsilon$.

So any real number lesser than $sup(A)+sup(B)$ fails to be an upper bound of $C$ and hence $Sup(C)=Sup(A)+Sup(B)$

Following from above the answer to your question is $3$

Comment: Pardon the use of Capital S and small s to write supremum. They mean the same.